# Separating multiple arrays of items into two columns in a balanced way

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, logic

Sorry for the non-descriptive title, I just wasn't sure how to describe this. On my website I have an FAQ page, and on that page are groups of Topics, and each topic has questions. For example:

```
FAQ
  - Topic 1
     - Question
     - Question
     - Question
  - Topic 2
     - Question
     - Question
     - Question
  - Topic 3
     - Question
     - Question
     - Question
     - Question
```

I need to split these topics into two clumns, so that they're balanced. For example, the most balanced way to separate the topics above into two columns would be to have Topic 1 and Topic 2 (60% of questions) in the left column, and then Topic 3 (40% of questions) in the right column. It would look like this:

[image: Illustration 1]

I can't figure out the logic behind what I need to do. The way I'm doing it now is to calculate a percent for each block, then iterate through the blocks and put them into the first column until the incremental percent is greater than 50, then switch to the 2nd column. This ends up looking like this:

[image: Illustration 2]

Obviously that isn't balanced. Is this seemingly simple task actually pretty complex, or am I totally missing something here? I'm coding this in PHP, but I tagged JavaScript as well since this seems to be more of a logic problem.

Comment: For javascript there's a masonry plugin, you can look into.

Comment: Are you asking _us_ what _your_ logic is?  Total questions = 10.  Midpoint = 5. Add `groups` to leftside while leftside count is < midpoint, then dump the remaining groups on the rightside.  Right?  Is there a case where this would not provide the desired effect?  ...and PHP is okay to solve logic problems with.  Are you going to provide us with an array of questions?  or any code to fix?  How do we answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa the midpoint technique is what I said I’m already doing but doesn’t divide them in a balanced way, since if you have 30/30/60 it will put 30 in the first column and 30/60 in the 2nd column. The 2nd graphic is the result of a 50% midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the logic properly, you want to fill up the leftside until 50% is met or exceeded then dump the rest into the rightside.

Here I use the `recursive` and the `regular` form of `count()` to calculate the number of questions, then I find the midpoint.

PHP: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4c097753e6729c46aac69bfd182224ea45f98dd))

```
$FAQ=[
    'Topic 1'=>['Question1','Question2','Question3'],
    'Topic 2'=>['Question4','Question5','Question6'],
    'Topic 3'=>['Question7','Question8','Question9','Question10']
];
$mid_point=(count($FAQ,1)-count($FAQ))/2;

$tally=0;
foreach($FAQ as $k=>$a){
    if($tally<=$mid_point){
        $leftside[$k]=$a;
    }else{
        $rightside[$k]=$a;
    }
    $tally+=count($a);
}

var_export($leftside);
echo "\n\n";
var_export($rightside);
```

Output:

```
// leftside array:
array (
  'Topic 1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Question1',
    1 => 'Question2',
    2 => 'Question3',
  ),
  'Topic 2' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Question4',
    1 => 'Question5',
    2 => 'Question6',
  ),
)

// rightside array
array (
  'Topic 3' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Question7',
    1 => 'Question8',
    2 => 'Question9',
    3 => 'Question10',
  ),
)
```

[Here is another demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/534c6c77aa4b4b17be7ea55f865ef9f2d10b1f62) where Topic 1 has 5 questions, Topic 2 has 3 questions and Topic 3 has 1 question.

Comment: @Gavin You didn't provide any code, so I just mocked some up to express the logic.  Is this what you are shooting for?  If these questions are coming from the database, you can just count num rows and divide by 2.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's still not balancing the items how I want them to though. For example, try this code with 5 items in `Topic 1`, 3 items in `Topic 2`, and 1 item in `Topic 3`. It will end up putting `Topic 1` and `Topic 2` in the first column (8 questions), and `Topic 3` alone in the 3rd column with only 1 question.

Comment: @Gavin removing `round()` fixed that case: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/534c6c77aa4b4b17be7ea55f865ef9f2d10b1f62

Comment: @Gavin is there a case where my solution lets you down?  I believe my solution is simpler than the one you have posted.  If it doesn't break for you, please award it the green tick so that your answer is deemed resolved in the system.  If it breaks, please provide the input array that breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question. Here's what I figured out. I'm sure it's not the best method, so if you have a better way please let me know.

```
$sections = array (
    array(
        'section_title' => 'Section 1',
        'items' => array (
            'Item 1',
            'Item 2',
            'Item 3'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'section_title' => 'Section 2',
        'items' => array (
            'Item 1',
            'Item 2',
            'Item 3'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'section_title' => 'Section 3',
        'items' => array (
            'Item 1',
            'Item 2',
            'Item 3',
            'Item 4'
        )
    )
);

$left_col = array();
$right_col = $sections; // Put all items into the right column initially

$left_col_height = 0;
$right_col_height = 0;

foreach ( $right_col as $arr ) {
    $right_col_height += count( $arr[ 'items' ] ); // Get the count of all items in the right column
}

foreach ( $right_col as $key => $val ) {
    // Get height/count of the current block of items
    $block_height = count( $val[ 'items' ] );
    // Get difference between height of right column and left column
    $cur_col_diff = $right_col_height - $left_col_height;
    // Calculate what the heights of the columns would be if the block was moved
    $next_left_col_height = $left_col_height + $block_height;
    $next_right_col_height = $right_col_height - $block_height;
    // Calculate what the difference between the two columns would be if the block was moved
    $next_col_diff = abs( $next_right_col_height - $next_left_col_height );
    if ( $next_col_diff < $cur_col_diff ) {
        // The difference betweens the columns would be less if the block was moved, so move it
        array_push( $left_col, $val );
        unset( $right_col[ $key ] );
        $left_col_height += $block_height;
        $right_col_height -= $block_height;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

[Here's the working PHP code.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65db9bb9f9f511011b4b35d27ee0a1886ae97e42)